# linux kernel 4.4 build error: garbage following instruction

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to build a custom linux kernel 4.4 running for AT91 with mostly default configuration that I set up from menuconfig. The build fails with the following error. The gcc version is 4.6.3 and the binutils version is 2.22. There is nothing obvious in main.c which is where the compilation is at the time of failure. Dont understand what to look for as I have run out of ideas.

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wp,-MD,init/.main.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/arm-2009q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/include -I./arch/arm/include -Iarch/arm/include/generated/uapi -Iarch/arm/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/arm/include/uapi -Iarch/arm/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 -march=armv7-a -msoft-float -Uarm -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -fno-stack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -gdwarf-2 -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(main)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(main)" -c -o init/.tmp_main.o init/main.c
/tmp/ccbj4Zgm.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccbj4Zgm.s:852: Error: garbage following instruction -- `dmb ishst'
/tmp/ccbj4Zgm.s:874: Error: garbage following instruction -- `dmb ishst'
/tmp/ccbj4Zgm.s:909: Error: garbage following instruction -- `dmb ish'
/tmp/ccbj4Zgm.s:921: Error: garbage following instruction -- `dsb ishst'
make[2]: *** [init/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [init] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your toolchain is working correctly? can you test if `gcc` can compile a simple "Hello, World!" program?

Comment: In the line you have **4.3.3** version while you are stating that you are using **4.6.3**. Is it a typo or what?

Comment: @HappyCactus - I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in a VM. I am able to build & run Hello World and a little more complex programs.

Comment: @0andriy, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @0andriy, yes the gcc version is 4.3.3

Comment: I had typed in the commands in the wrong window, the linux version 4.3.3 and binutils version is 2.19

Comment: *"I am able to build & run Hello World and a little more complex programs"* -- What does the `file` command report for those programs?

Comment: Had a bunch of environment issues that was causing the issue. Redid a bunch of things and resolved the issue. Thanks guys for asking the right questions which led me to look at the configs.